# C# .net Library Question

Tags: c#

What are the top 5 most useful/used .net libraries a C# developer would need to know?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take poll questions to programmers.stackexchange.com, this is Q+A, one Q, one A.

Comment: I'll be amazed if everyone names the same 5.

Comment: @kirk.burleson - hence, "Subjective and Argumentative"

Answer (score 3):

See this thread:
[Most useful free .NET libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662956/most-useful-free-net-libraries)

Answer (score 1):

System,
System.XML,
System.Web,
System.Drawing,
System.Data

or what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Mine would be the following

Nhibernate

Structure Map

Lucene

Rhino Mocks

Nunit

Answer (score 0):

nUnit, Moq, Spring.NET, nHibernate, and Lucene would be my choices.